# Sort information in Excel displayed in "cards"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sorting

I'm looking to create data "cards" in Excel which is a way to visually display information next to an image:

[image: Sample data card]

The reason to display information this way is because I want to always be able to view an image first (that's what the black rectangle is), view some of its attributes (the field names, which never change), view the data against those attributes, assign a value to those data, then finally tally the individual values to produce a final value or "score" at the bottom right of the card.

As an example, let's say we have a building named "Eiffel Tower". Field1 might be "Height", Data1 would be "150m", and I might give that a value of 15. Once I go through all fields and give them a value (e.g. the building's age, city, design etc.) I would get a total value for that building, and I could compare it against all the other buildings on my sheet if, say, I wanted to find which building I valued most.

So far so good. The problem is that I want to be able to sort these cards on one sheet by final value (usually highest to lowest). It would also be nice to be able to filter/sort by data in field names, but this is less important for now.

Obviously I know that if I lay out the data in a typical database fashion (field names as column headers, data in rows) then I can simply sort by the final value column which is trivial. The problem is that I need to also see the images based on what is being sorted, and the images are always portrait orientation. It's also more visually pleasing looking at all of the information in "cards" like this, rather than as one massive table (without any images).

Is there a way to sort my "cards" on one sheet?

Update: Thanks to the trigger-happy mods who were so keen to close my question as a duplicate, but that doesn't solve my problem. If you read my question, you would note that I had photos next to my data, and obviously sorting just the data does not preserve the photo position. I need to preserve the photo position alongside the data when sorting.

Comment: if you read carefully your original question, you'll notice that the only reference to images is the orientation. Have you researched image anchoring on Excel? Maybe anchor it to the cell with the word "Name" as that won't be included in sorting (I assume) therefore won't change position. It might be an idea to remove the snarky update and re-word your question so that it contains all the relevant information and requirements, and only the relevant info and requirements.

Comment: @Peregrino69 My first line literally says I want to display information next to an image. Even if I didn't explicitly say that, any reasonable person would infer that the information needs to be next to the image once sorted. Thanks for your helpful suggestion, but don't worry about it - I'll seek an answer on a friendlier site.